# Is it safe to short signal to max in a volume control potentiometer in a video doorbell?

Tags: potentiometer, short-circuit

I have a video doorbell as in the picture below:

[image: video doorbell]

However, I cannot hear the bell when it rings. So I opened the device to get to the control volume potentiometer. As in picture below:

[image: volume control]

What I did is I have shorted the signal pin (in the middle) to the max volume pin ( in the far left) with a short wire. And now the sound works when it rings. I didn't want to remove the whole knob because I have to heat the board. I dont wanna risk damage it.

I just have some worries that someone might lower the volunm knob all the way down, in which case the max pin will be shorted to ground pin( in the far right). Is that dangerous?

And if it's dangerous, what would be a good solution to fix this without buying a new potentiometer?

Comment: Yes, it is dangerous. You gave basically turned your potentiometer - which has a fixed resistance across two of it's terminals into a rheostat, which does not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it only dangerous if someone lowered the knob? Or dangerous regardless?

Comment: Assuming the potentiometer is working in it's full possible range, the only "safe" state would be when it is on the "max" position, which will give the resistance between the terminals as designed for the circuit. Any other position will lower this resistance and the circuit will not work as intended.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I have turned the knob to max, and then I have put a tape on it so no one can change the volume. I think that's safe right?

Comment: Turn the knob to max, and if it has a screw holding the plastic thumbwheel on, remove the screw and the thumbwheel.  Then *nobody* can turn it, accidental or not.

Comment: Remove the short. If you're willing to tape the knob or remove it after setting volume to max, you've solved the problem.